# How can I enable user namespaces and have it persist after reboot?

Tags: debian, namespace, sysctl, podman

When I run podman I get,

```
$ podman info
cannot clone: Operation not permitted
user namespaces are not enabled in /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone
Error: cannot re-exec process
```

How can I enable user namespaces and have them persist after reboot? I am using Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable user namespaces like this,

```
sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

And you can have it persist after reboot in Debian by running this,

```
echo "kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Any idea, how do we get this fixed with Redhat 8.4?                                             
podman version 3.4.2                                        
podman ps -a
Error: cannot re-exec process    podman info
Error: cannot re-exec process

Comment: @GopinathKarangula Is this actually related?